# Google Maps API - when drawing a rectangle, the rectangle is not drawn where it should be, but shifted within the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vuejs3

I am using vue3 and Google Maps API with drawing manager. The problem is that when I try to draw a rectangle on the map, the resulted rectangle is drawn out of position (shifted left and up), not where it should be. Also the click event of the rectangle (when I try to click within its boundaries) is working exactly  the same manner: the click event is working out of the rectangle shifted exactly the same manner somewhere on the map surface, not within the rectangle. I am using VUE 3, and Google Maps Api.

```
const loader = new Loader({
    apiKey: 'xxxxx',
    version: 'weekly',
});

const mapid = ref();

loader.load().then(async () => {
    const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary('maps');
    const { drawing } = await google.maps.importLibrary('drawing');

    let map = new Map(mapid.value, {
        center: { lat: 47.1611615, lng: 19.5057541 },
        zoom: 8,
        streetViewControl: false,
    });

    const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
        drawingControl: true,

        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE,
            ],
        },

        rectangleOptions: { clickable: true, draggable: true, editable: true },
    });

    drawingManager.setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (event) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(event.overlay, 'click', function (e) {
            emit('overlayClicked', event.overlay.bounds);
        });

        drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
    });
});
```

The vue template:

```
<template>
    <div
        ref="mapid"
        class="h-96 w-full"
    ></div>
</template>
```

Anybody has idea what happens here?[image]

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, [stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-draw-polygon-google-maps-rytwjk?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts), it could be that your problem is placed somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Nils! Thanks for your help. So, at least I can be certain about the code. I am lost where to start to find out what happens here then.